# How to prevent Android app minimizes on phone lock

Tags: android, android-studio

i am having an issue with my app which might be multiple issues i don't know and are hoping for answers or pointers in the right direction.
The issue: I have an app which works to my liking. The app has 1 Activity and from there i manage different fragments that provide the actual content for my app
When I lock my phone (on purpose or because it was idle for some time) and then unlock it again, my app has minimized.
Other apps (like gMail) simply reappear in maximized state.
Now just to be clear: i an NOT trying to disable the lock screen of bypass the lock screen. I just want my app to remain maximized when i unlock my phone.
Now all of this might have some relation with the fact that i am struggeling to get the saveState to work. I also see issues when i rotate the phone. The app does not crash (solved that) but always reverts to the first fragment (called from the onCreate method).

**Update**
I got the saveState to work. Now when i rotate my phone all data and which is the current fragment is kept. But still when my phone locks and i unlock it the app is no longer the foreground app. If i then reactivate it, it starts in my first fragment again. Almost like the savestate options are ignored.

**Update 2**
I put some logging on the "onSaveState"-method and the "onRestoreState"-method. What i see is that when i rotate my phone both are call. When my phone goes into lock it calls the "onSaveState" but then when i unlock my phone no "onResumeState" is called. Aanother thing in that in the emulator my app is not move to the background but on my phone it is.
In both cases no "onResumeState". This also happens (no 'onResumeState") when my app starts the gallary to get a photo.
i seems the "onRestoreState" is only called in some situations and not all.
To put in in lists:
Note i did not log all methods to keep it a bit simple

```
Start app         Rotate phone              Screen off/on
---------         ------------              -------------
onCreate          onStop                    onStop
OnResume          onSaveInstanceState       onSaveInstanceState
                  OnCreate                  onResume
                   |_state is filled
                  OnRestoreInstanceState
                  onResume
```

As you can see No SaveState info is retrieved when the phone screen turned off/on. I am lost.

**Update 3**
i rewrote a lot of my code and the save/restore state now work when i do a phone rotate. Howevery i keep having strange behaviour with locking/unlocking my phone that does NOT happen on the emulator.
So i have activity that starts 1 of 2 fragments:
Fragment A: holds an recyclerview
Fragment B: holds an tabview with again 3 fragments.
Important to note is that fragment B has an override of the onSaveInstanceState implemented, but still i cannot understand why fragments B forces a complete recreate of my activity.

```
Fragment A             Fragment B
-----------            -----------
"lock phone"           "lock phone"
onPause                onPause
onStop                 onStop
onSaveInstanceState    onSaveInstanceState
"unlock phone"         "unlock phone"
onRestart              onCreate (saveState == null)
onStart                onStart
onResume               onResume
```

I hope somebody has an idea. for sure i am doing something wrong but i cannot reason where or why

Comment: "Minimized" isn't a concept on Android.  Do you mean it's no longer the foreground activity?  But based on your other descriptions, your problem is likely state save/restore and activity recreation.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, sorry i indeed mean 'foreground activity.  i am slowly making progress in the save/restore state so i am hoping that will fix my issue